# Error importing database in Windows Azure

Tags: backup, restore, ms-sql, azure

Just to test the MSSQL backup/restore capabilities of Windows Azure, I selected a test database and chose the "Export" option. It prompted me to select a storage location and I chose an appropriate one. The export process completed "successfully".

When I attempted to import the exported file without making any changes to the existing database, the import completed successfully.

However, when I inserted a test row into a table in the existing database and then tried to import the backup over the existing database (theoretically reverting the inserted row), I was met with the following error:

> Error encountered during the service operation. Data cannot be
>   imported into target because it contains one or more user objects.
>   Import should be performed against a new, empty database. Error SQL0:
>   Data cannot be imported into target because it contains one or more
>   user objects. Import should be performed against a new, empty
>   database.

Things I have tried:

- Removing the existing database (keeping the existing server in-tact) and importing to an empty server instance
- Removing the existing database, creating a new/empty database with the same name, and importing over it.

Each time I get the same error as above.

Of all the things I don't know, which of them can be taught to me to resolve the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer shortly after asking this question. It's quite silly now that I think about it.

After the first successful import, the azure UI did not update to show the imported database, which had imported to its default backup name. (BlahBlahTest-2013-1-8-57)

So in all subsequent attempts to import the database, it was basically telling me that the database was already there, even though it wasn't showing up in the UI. After some handle jiggling, I could see the imported database in the azure management UI.

Result: Export/Import MSSQL database seems to work fine on a small database. Just be sure to refresh the UI after an import. (Log out and then back in, if necessary)